# How to prevent the virtual keyboard of mobile devices from showing up with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, virtual-keyboard

The question is self explanatory. I would like to prevent the keyboard from being shown when i foucus/click on input fields like type="text", number and so on.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: So, how are users of touch devices supposed to type into the input?

Comment: It's a particular application with particular requirements. The input is made through a custom keyboard that is launched programatically.